# How mirror two SQL Servers Express with different versions using the Log Shipping method?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, readonly, log-shipping

I have a desktop application accessing a SQL Server database. I have a web application, running on a remote computer (Amazon EC2).

I tried mirroring between two SQL Servers using Log Shipping method, but due the different SQL Server versions, the database does not restore in STANDBY mode, even if the Amazon EC2 SQL Server version is newer than local SQL Server.

For the records: the online application may access the database in read-only mode.

I'm asking for some help with ideas to solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use transnational replication to transfer data. If there is possibility update different rows in both DB at the same time, you can use merge replication.